# Error with opening cuda libraries. Not found while being on my pc

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run a programm with tensorflow 2.4.1 and cuda11.2 , cudnn 8 installed.

but i am getting the following error:

```
2021-02-20 11:19:58.133537: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-20 11:19:58.134134: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-02-20 11:19:58.182437: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-20 11:19:58.182953: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:21:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3080 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.905GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 9.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 707.88GiB/s
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183001: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183460: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:4b:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3080 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.905GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 9.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 707.88GiB/s
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183520: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183559: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183599: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183630: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183660: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183691: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183721: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183839: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-02-20 11:19:58.183846: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-02-20 11:19:58.184162: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-20 11:19:58.186311: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-20 11:19:58.186324: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-20 11:19:58.186328: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      
2021-02-20 11:19:58.983593: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-02-20 11:19:58.984705: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 3693110000 Hz
```

I find the files in my pc but they have a weird arrow next to them, a purple upwards diagonal arrow.
I do not get why this error exists. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: The version of tensorflow you are using requires CUDA 11.0, not CUDA 11.2

Comment: but cuda is backwards compatible isn't it ? ad also i have the file, i dont get why its not finding it @talonmies

Comment: No it is not backward compatible. You need the *exact* version. And no you don't have those files, whether you think you do or not

Comment: @talonmies but I am looking at them in my cuda-11.2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

From the error code, it shows you need to install `Tensorflow-gpu 2.4.0` compatible `CUDA 11.0` and `cuDNN 8.0`.

Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) to know about `TensorFlow` compatible `CUDA` and `cuDNN` configuration details and for [GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements) Support.

Also you can surpass these warnings (W) and informational (I) messages using below code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Let us know if issue still persists.